# How to use Node.js without admin rights on a mac?

Tags: environment-variables

I'm trying to use Node.js on my work computer but I don't have admin rights.  I'm wondering how I can install Node.js on mac without having admin rights.

I found a tutorial, which is for Windows but still has been helpful. But, I'm stuck at the "Configure the PATH" step where I have to add to the $PATH variable. How can I complete that step on a mac?

Here's the tutorial: 
https://theshravan.net/blog/how-to-use-node-and-npm-without-installation-or-admin-rights/

Comment: for one particular window, you can set PATH by `export PATH="a/b/c". No need to edit `bash_profile` then

Comment: @ankii Do you mean set a temporary PATH in terminal whenever I want to use node?

Comment: is ~/.bash_profile not editable by standard user ? if not, then yes a temporary edit should work. let me correct myself, it should be `PATH="a/b/c":"$PATH"`. In this window, this PATH will be used. verify using `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `~/.bash_profile` not editable by standard user, then  a temporary edit to `PATH` should work. It should be

```
PATH="a/b/c":"$PATH"
```

In this window, this `PATH` will be used. verify using `echo $PATH`

Comment: So, I'm having another issue related to this. When I try to globally install packages with npm, I get this error: `sh: node: command not found`

Comment: are you sure that bash_profile is not edible ? though there would be bigger problems with installing packages as a standard user than PATH.

Comment: Yes the bash_profile is editable

Comment: then add this line there, no need  to bother about window specific PATHs

Comment: will that fix the error?

Comment: yes. make sure to reopen terminal after that

Comment: Okay, I changed the path and I'm able to successfully download the packages. But the commands for the packages don't work.

Comment: as I said there, use full path, node relative. and prepend it, not append it.

Comment: Okay. This is what I did: `PATH=/Users/user1/Tools/nodejs:$PATH`
Is that right?

Comment: yes, putting them in quotes won't harm. see in the answer ^

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using nvm to install node because you don't need admin rights to do that. You just need to have the Command Line Tools.